# Disable action bar in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I used `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE_BAR);` for disable the title bar.
I just wondering is there has anyway to enable the Title Bar after use above code?

Comment: actionbar and titlebar are 2 different things

Comment: What do you want? Do you want to again show the TitleBar after disabling it ?

Comment: You can hide and show `ActionBar`... see `actionBar.hide()` and `actionBar.show()`...

Answer (score 0):

You can take control of the visibility of the action bar and show/hide in any activity you want by defining the attribute `android:windowActionBar` in `styles.xml` and use it accordingly in the Android Manifest file.

For example, write this in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And now in your Android Manifest file,

```
<activity
            android:name="com.package.name.ActivityName"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" >
 </activity>
```

You can call `android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"` to any activity that you don't want the action bar to be displayed.